# Think Python - Can't get tkinter to work

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am all new to everything about coding and programming, and I'm right now reading the book Think Python. Now I have to make tkinter work, so I can import the module TurtleWorld. First I try to import tkinter just to see that it work, and it does. Then when I'm trying to import TurtleWorld, suddenly there is no module called tkinter? I have no idea what to do, feels like I have been doing everything I could find! I'm using python 3.4.1 and I haven't downloading tcl or swampy cause they already came with python.

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> import swampy.TurtleWorld
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import swampy.TurtleWorld
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\swampy\TurtleWorld.py", line 8, in <module>
from Tkinter import TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, END, LAST, NONE, SUNKEN
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Python 3.4.1 and according to the [Swampy: Installation Instructions](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html) you need to have Python 2 installed to use the Tkinter module. Python 2 is the version of Python used in *Think Python*, and you will not be able to use Swampy with Python 3. The current version of Python 2 is in the Python 2.7 series.

To see if you have the Tkinter module, at the Python prompt, type:

```
import Tkinter
```

Note that the word Tkinter is case sensitive and the tkinter module (not the Tkinter module) should be used with Python 3.

Comment: When i typed Tkinter instead of tkinter it said that I didn't have it, but I thought as I am using Python 3.4 I was suppose to type tkinter, and then it would work? But I guess that's not the case. So should I use Python 2 instead or what can I do to make it work with Python 3?

I also found it strange that I first can import tkinter and then with swampy it doesnt work. As it says in the Swampy installation instructions this wouldnt be the case if i didn't have tkinter to start with. Am I wrong?

Comment: Since you are reading *Think Python* you should install Python 2 and use the Tkinter module with Python 2. You can have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed at the same time, but note that the syntax of Python 2 and Python 3 is different in some small ways. Also you can have similar modules for Python 2 and Python 3 installed at the same time. In Ubuntu, the Python 2 packages usually start with the prefix *python-* and the Python 3 packages usually start with the prefix *python3-*.